# What are these vintage LEGO-like window pieces?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, vintage

I have a bag of square white vintage LEGO-like windows but with grooves on 2 sides and square pegs on 2 sides.

Has clear "window" pieces and these beam-like bars, the pegs seem to fit the grooves on the other parts. Any help on identifying manufacturers or age?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

These parts are from [Supercity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_City_(toy)), made by Ideal

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!  Was driving me crazy trying to find it.